# Could II7 be blocking Javascript to maintain scroll position on page refresh?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have an asp.net application with a webform that has a user control that is set to refresh every x seconds using the `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />`

When I run the web application on my local machine with visual studio the jscript to maintain scroll position works fine.  When I deploy to the server and run it from a remote client it doesn't work, however, it does work when I run it from the server locally.

Is there a config on the server I'm missing?

Rich

> Edit: After doing a little more
>   research on the issue, it looks like
>   the problem maybe the result of the
>   script which I got from
>   http://en.hasheminezhad.com/scrollsaver.
>   Others have reported a problem with
>   the script not working on the page in
>   the root folder, which seems to be the
>   case for me. I've asked the author of
>   the script for a possible solution
>   thru his blog.
>   I'll let you all know what I find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than your edit you should check which security zone your web server is in.

What happens sometimes is that you test locally in local intranet or trusted zone. Then you run against a site that is in internet zone, and things stop working.

Comment: you got it! I'll need to get with my sys admin to adjust the settings for the security zone the web server is in (I think this needs to be done on the DNS server), but I was able to add the site to my trusted sites on IE and the script seems to work fine now for refreshes initiated by the browser. I'll let everyone know what the final results are. Thanks!!!